# python argparse to handle arbitrary numeric options (like HEAD(1))

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optional-parameters, argparse

Is there a way to trick `argparse` into accepting arbitrary numeric arguments like `HEAD(1)`?

```
head -5 test.txt
```

is equivalent to

```
head -n 5 test.txt
```

My current approach is to use `parse_known_args()` and then handle the remainder, but I'd wish there was something a tad more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither agrparse nor optparse supports this.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2021?

Comment: @RichardNeumann I see nothing like that https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Believe its been possible (with minor caveats) for years.  See the answer I recently posted.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is easy, however you have to use a positional instead of an option.

(Usually such an argument is an essential one, and required/positional is a good choice.  It doesn't have to be required however, see `nargs='?'`.)
If you want to support both forms, you could copy the option into the primary value and use that:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('quantity', nargs='?', help='…')
parser.add_argument('-n', dest='quantity_opt')

args = parser.parse_args()
if args.quantity_opt:  # it's clobberin' time!
    args.quantity = args.quantity_opt

print('parsed:', args)
```

**Prefer Integers?**

Passing `type=int` to `add_argument()` works as well.  `abs()` (absolute value) could be useful if you want positive values only.

**Examples:**

```
$ test.py 42
parsed: Namespace(quantity='42', quantity_opt=None)

$ test.py -n 42
parsed: Namespace(quantity='42', quantity_opt='42')  # clobbered

$ test.py -163
parsed: Namespace(quantity='-163', quantity_opt=None)

$ test.py -n -163
parsed: Namespace(quantity='-163', quantity_opt='-163')  # clobbered
```

This is good because from then on you can just refer to `args.quantity`—client code has no need to know if it came from the positional or option.

**Digression:**

If you're tempted to stick something else non-numeric in there, such as a `-5:00`, beware you'll typically need to use `--` in front of it.  See: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing

I found a way around that as well, need to `parse_known_args()` and then use the unrecognized remainder to shift the other fields back to where they belong.  A custom class should probably work as well, but haven't yet looked.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description='Argparse with numeric arguments')
parser.add_argument('-0', action='store_true', help='null separator')
args = parser.parse_args()
print vars(args)['0']
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually you can use an Action class to implement head like arguments in argparse.  Here is an example program that will take "-n ##" or "-##" arguments and print the number.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser, Action, SUPPRESS
class UpdateCount(Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        digit = option_string[1]
        increment = int(digit)
        previous = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        if previous is None:
            previous = 0
        else:
            previous *= 10
        setattr(namespace, self.dest, previous + increment)

parser = ArgumentParser(description='parse -## type options')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-n', type=int, default=10, metavar='#',
                   help='specify a number (-# also works) (default=10)')
group.add_argument('-0', '-1', '-2', '-3', '-4', '-5', '-6', '-7', '-8', '-9',
                   dest='count', default=None, nargs=0, action=UpdateCount, help=SUPPRESS)

def main():
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.count is None:
        count = args.n
    else:
        count = args.count
    print(count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and here are some example output

```
$ ./argparse_number_option -h
usage: argparse_number_option [-h] [-n #]

parse -## type options

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -n #        specify a number (-# also works) (default=10)
$ ./argparse_number_option -n 123
123
$ ./argparse_number_option -123
123
$ ./argparse_number_option -123 -n 34
usage: argparse_number_option [-h] [-n #]
argparse_number_option: error: argument -n: not allowed with argument -0/-1/-2/-3/-4/-5/-6/-7/-8/-9
$
```

Comment: That is delightfully perverse! Unfortunately, it doesn't mix well with other commands, eg, "-4h0" gives the help message rather than an error about using a non-integer, and "-2 -8" gives 28 instead of either an error or using one of 8 or 2.

Answer (score -3):

As an alternative to @vault's answer using `vars(args)['0]` you could also use `args.__dict__['0']`